# C# How to set a NewLine in Label.text for a CartItem[]?

Tags: c#-4.0, newline

How to set a NewLine in `Label.text` for a `CartItem[]`? `Environment.NewLine` or `\r\n` does not work.

```
CartItem[] items = Profile.Cart.GetItems();
  foreach (CartItem i in items)
     Label4.Text += i.curDvd.Title + ",$" + i.curDvd.UnitPrice + "*" + i.Quantity + System.Environment.NewLine+"\r\n";
```

It can display everything in 1 line, but tried `\r\n` and `Enviroment.NewLine`, nothing changed.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

In a web application you should use `<br/>` if you want new line. Unfortunately you cannot use a label in this case as it will automatically HTML encode the text. You could use a repeater at the place of this label:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("Title") %>, $<%# Eval("Price") %>
        <br/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and in your code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        CartItem[] items = Profile.Cart.GetItems();
        rep.DataSource = items.Select(x => new
        {
            Title = x.curDvd.Title,
            Price = x.curDvd.UnitPrice * x.Quantity
        });
        rep.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Another possible template is to use divs:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div><%# Eval("Title") %>, $<%# Eval("Price") %></div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: items.Select  It shows CartItem does not contain a definition for Select

Comment: @jenifer, add a `using System.Linq;` statement to your page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using more than one "\n" ?